# Warn in case of new questions with tags of outdated Ubuntu versions

Tags: feature-request, tags, closed-questions

I have asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718330/update-php-5-3-2-to-5-3-3-or-5-4-on-ubuntu-10-04) yesterday, which was for Ubuntu 10.04. I wasn't aware that it is not allowed to ask questions for outdated Ubuntu versions.

As you can see, I have tagged the question as [10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.04), so the system could have identified my misbehavior in advance and inform me that it is not allowed to ask questions regarding that version.

Do we want such a feature?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the description of the 10.04 tag, it states

> The third Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu. Released April
>   2010, and no longer supported since May 2013.

Also this is out lined in the [asking section](https://askubuntu.com/help) of the help page.

Perhaps updating the tags for unsupported releases could be a simple solution to your issue, something like

> The third Long Term Support (LTS) release of Ubuntu. Released April
>   2010, and no longer supported since May 2013.
>   This release of Ubuntu is [end of life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) and no longer eligible for support on
>   AskUbuntu

Do not use would not work, there are situations where the tag is valid, for example an upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04, would be on topic, as the current version is 12.04, but the tag is relevant because they upgraded from 10.04.

Comment: The tag description is ambiguous in the sense whether Ubuntu is no longer supported or the tag on askubuntu is no longer supported, or both. I agree regarding the help section, but since the tag exists on the site, it seems legitimate to use it (until you read the help page).

Comment: I am not voting against your feature request, I am just saying, the information is available but perhaps unsupported tags could have there descriptions updated to reflect tour comment.

Comment: Yes, a bit DO NOT USE (anymore) tag description would definitely be helpful

Comment: See my update...